# Unable to clone LibreOffice git repository

Tags: git, libreoffice

I'm trying to follow the instructions on [this LibreOffice page](http://www.libreoffice.org/get-involved/developers/) to clone the LibreOffice source code, but It's not working.  It looks like I can't even ping their server.  Is their server down, or am I just missing something?  I've done some googling, but I just can't figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
jared@ubuntu:/media/windowsJaredHome/Jareds Documents/LibreOfficeSourceCode$ git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/core
Cloning into core...
anongit.freedesktop.org[0: 131.252.210.161]: errno=Connection refused
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection refused)
jared@ubuntu:/media/windowsJaredHome/Jareds Documents/LibreOfficeSourceCode$ ping anongit.freedesktop.org
PING molly.freedesktop.org (131.252.210.161) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- molly.freedesktop.org ping statistics ---
21 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 20129ms
```

Comment: This sucks. The whole linux graphic stack is dependent on this git repository.

Comment: Found this: http://www.mail-archive.com/xorg-devel@lists.x.org/msg28311.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a programming question, but yes their git repo does seem to be experiencing problems.